# Webview current url for blackberry

Tags: events, blackberry, webview, load, appcelerator

I have added a webview to my window as shown on below.

```
<Alloy>

    <Window>

     <WebView top="150" id="webContent" width="300px" height="300px" borderColor="red" 
        borderWidth="2px" url="http://www.google.com"></WebView>

    </Window>

</Alloy>
```

And added a load event on controller.

```
$.webContent.addEventListener('load', checkState);
function checkState(e){

 alert($.webContent.evalJS("document.title"));
}
```

But every time it shows undefined on alert, whenever I change url. It works fine on IOS.

And also the border and border color was not displaying in case of BB.

Please suggest.

Can also [check](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/159120/webview-current-url-for-blackberry)